# Python: Transform a Dictionary into a list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.7

Basically, I have a dictionary that I want to transform into a list of lists (with each component list consisting of the key and value from the dictionary).

The reason I am doing this is so that I can iterate through this new list with a for loop and do something with both the key and the value. If there is an easier way to do this, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the `dict`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
for key, value in my_dict.iteritems()
```

This will iterate through the dictionary, storing each key in `key` and each value in `value`.
See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems).

Comment: In Python 3, use `for key, value in iter(my_dict.items())` instead.

Answer (score 30):

How about this solution ?
No need to make your hand dirty by unnecessary looping through, cleaner and shorter !!!

```
d = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
list(map(list, d.items()))
[['a', 1], ['c', 3], ['b', 2]]
```

Answer (score 3):

to iterate over a dictionary's keys and values:

```
for key, value in D.iteritems():
    # do something with them
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking for but this is how I would turn a dictionary into a list using its key as a tupled value.

```
new_list = []
dict = {test:1, test:2, test:3}
for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    new_list.append((key, value))
```

Here is where I am doing something very similar to what you want.

```
 if str(vm_mor) == vm['config.annotation']:
    annotation= pickle.load(open(str(vm_mor), "rb"))
    print annotation

    sql_check_exist = '''select a.vm_mor, b.license_id, c.product from vms a , vm_licenses b, licenses c where a.vm_id = b.vm_id and b.license_id = c.license_id and a.vm_mor = '%s' ''' % str(vm_mor) 
    cursor_exist.execute(sql_check_exist)
    database_license = []

    for vm_mor, license_id, product in cursor_exist:
       database_license.append((product,license_id))

    checklist_database_license = [int(i[1]) for i in database_license] #make a list of 2nd element of all the tuples in the database_license list
    check_me = annotation['license']

    for product, license_id in check_me:
       if license_id in checklist_database_license:
          print "do nothing"
       else:
          del annotation['license']
          annotation['license'] = database_license
          change = True

    if change == True:         
       change_annotation(vm_mor, annotation)
       change = False    

 else:
    print vm['config.name']
    pickle_mor(vm_mor,vm)
```